# HIde/Show Rows based on Drop Down List Numeric Selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have a drop down list that has numbers 0 to 10. Zero hides rows 1 to 10, 1 only shows row 1, 2 only shows rows 1 & 2 and so on up to nbr 10. This is working as expected, I can go up from nbr 1 to 10 and display all the correct amount of rows.

What I can't do is for example if I have selected row 5 and then select row 2, I can't hide row 5 to 3.

I'm quite new to VBA and can't think how to do this, if I add another line that sets the same nbr to EntireRow.Hidden = true for obvious reasons that doesn't work, as the same number has conflicting actions. Can anyone help me with this?

```
If Target.Address = Range("SRUAdd").Address Then
        If Range("SRUAdd").Value = "0" Then    ' hide rows 1 to 10
            Rows((Target.Row + 4) & ":" & (Target.Row + 13)).EntireRow.Hidden = True 

        ElseIf Range("SRUAdd").Value = "1" Then    ' show row #1
            Rows(Target.Row + 4).EntireRow.Hidden = False

        ElseIf Range("SRUAdd").Value = "2" Then    ' show row #2
            Rows((Target.Row + 4) & ":" & (Target.Row + 5)).EntireRow.Hidden = False

        ElseIf Range("SRUAdd").Value = "3" Then    ' show row #3
            Rows((Target.Row + 4) & ":" & (Target.Row + 6)).EntireRow.Hidden = False

        ElseIf Range("SRUAdd").Value = "4" Then    ' show row #4
            Rows((Target.Row + 4) & ":" & (Target.Row + 7)).EntireRow.Hidden = False

        ElseIf Range("SRUAdd").Value = "5" Then    ' show row #5
            Rows((Target.Row + 4) & ":" & (Target.Row + 8)).EntireRow.Hidden = False

        ElseIf Range("SRUAdd").Value = "6" Then    ' show row #6
            Rows((Target.Row + 4) & ":" & (Target.Row + 9)).EntireRow.Hidden = False

        ElseIf Range("SRUAdd").Value = "7" Then    ' show row #7
            Rows((Target.Row + 4) & ":" & (Target.Row + 10)).EntireRow.Hidden = False

        ElseIf Range("SRUAdd").Value = "8" Then    ' show row #8
            Rows((Target.Row + 4) & ":" & (Target.Row + 11)).EntireRow.Hidden = False

        ElseIf Range("SRUAdd").Value = "9" Then    ' show row #9
            Rows((Target.Row + 4) & ":" & (Target.Row + 12)).EntireRow.Hidden = False 

        ElseIf Range("SRUAdd").Value = "10" Then    ' show row #10
            Rows((Target.Row + 4) & ":" & (Target.Row + 13)).EntireRow.Hidden = False 
        End If
    End If
```

Expected result is I'd like to show and hide the correct rows based on the number selected from the drop down list. Current result is only the correct rows are displayed based on the drop down selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic is to hide everything and then unhide relevant rows. Actually you do not need the condition `If Range("SRUAdd").Value = "0" Then`. Directly start from `If Range("SRUAdd").Value = "1" Then`. You may also use `Select Case`.

Is this what you are trying (**Untested**)?

```
Dim sRow As Long, toRow As Long

If Target.Address = Range("SRUAdd").Address Then
    Rows((Target.Row + 4) & ":" & (Target.Row + 13)).EntireRow.Hidden = True

    sRow = Target.Row + 2

    Select Case Range("SRUAdd").Value
        Case 1: toRow = Target.Row + 4
        Case 2: toRow = Target.Row + 5
        Case 3: toRow = Target.Row + 6
        Case 4: toRow = Target.Row + 7
        Case 5: toRow = Target.Row + 8
        Case 6: toRow = Target.Row + 9
        Case 7: toRow = Target.Row + 10
        Case 8: toRow = Target.Row + 11
        Case 9: toRow = Target.Row + 12
        Case 10: toRow = Target.Row + 13
    End Select

    If toRow <> 0 Then Rows(sRow & ":" & toRow).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
```

**Edit:**

> I can hide the 2nd table with the Rows((Target.Row + 44) & ":" & (Target.Row + 53)).EntireRow.Hidden = True code, I can't figure out how to add the extra code to the case section. I've tried a few things but its not working... I take it "Case 1, Case 2" etc relates to the number selected in the drop down box? I have tried Case 1: toRow = Target.Row + 4 + 44 but this doesn't work. – stacson76 3 hours ago

You have to handle the table separately. See this.

```
Dim sRowTblA As Long, toRowTblA As Long
Dim sRowTblB As Long, toRowTblB As Long

If Target.Address = Range("SRUAdd").Address Then
    Rows((Target.Row + 4) & ":" & (Target.Row + 13)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows((Target.Row + 44) & ":" & (Target.Row + 53)).EntireRow.Hidden = True

    sRowTblA = Target.Row + 2
    sRowTblB = Target.Row + 44

    Select Case Range("SRUAdd").Value
        Case 1
            toRowTblA = Target.Row + 4
            toRowTblB = Target.Row + 44
        Case 2
            toRowTblA = Target.Row + 5
            toRowTblB = Target.Row + 45
        Case 3
            toRowTblA = Target.Row + 6
            toRowTblB = Target.Row + 46
        Case 4
            toRowTblA = Target.Row + 7
            toRowTblB = Target.Row + 47
        '
        '~~> And So on
        '
    End Select

    If toRowTblA <> 0 Then Rows(sRowTblA & ":" & toRowTblA).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    If toRowTblB <> 0 Then Rows(sRowTblB & ":" & toRowTblB).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
```

Comment: Yep that did the trick, thanks! I also have the same table further down the page, which is a mirror image of this one. How do I add this to the code so when nbr 1 is selected row 1 is selected in both tables?

Comment: Simply add more code. For example add one more line below `Rows((Target.Row + 4) & ":" & (Target.Row + 13)).EntireRow.Hidden = True`. There change `+4` and `+13`. Respectively change other values in in Select Case

Comment: I can hide the 2nd table with the ```Rows((Target.Row + 44) & ":" & (Target.Row + 53)).EntireRow.Hidden = True``` code, I can't figure out how to add the extra code to the case section. I've tried a few things but its not working... I take it "Case 1, Case 2" etc relates to the number selected in the drop down box? I have tried ```Case 1: toRow = Target.Row + 4 + 44``` but this doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't think to do that, fantastic thanks - it is now working as expected! Thanks for sharing that with me, much appreciated.